# How to add a string to rows having some keywords using python

Tags: python, list, file, with-statement

I have several files (named as `mod0.msh`, `mod1.msh` and so on) and want to add a string ( `lower_dimensional_block`) at the end of some rows of these files using python. At the moment I am giving the number of lines and add the string at the end but I want to use some words of the lines rather than numbers. This is some first lines of my files:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$PhysicalNames
13
1 10 "W_1"
1 11 "W_2"
2 8 "fault2"
...
```

I have also a list which has the number of lines which I want to add string:

```
adding_str = [6,7]
```

This is also my code:

```
from fileinput import FileInput
for idx in range(2):# it means I have two files
    with FileInput(f'mod{idx}.msh', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as in_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(in_file, start=1):
            for j in keywords:
                print(
                    line.rstrip(),
                    end=' lower_dimensional_block\n' if j in line else '\n'
                )
```

But, I have a list of key words and want to add the string at the end of each line that has one of these key words:

```
keywords=['W_1', 'W_2']
```

I do appreciate any help to do such thing in python. This is my expected output:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$PhysicalNames
13
1 10 "W_1" lower_dimensional_block
1 11 "W_2" lower_dimensional_block
2 8 "fault2"
...
```

Comment: Could you please give more explanation as to what you're doing and what you need help with, I'm lost

Comment: Dear @Corralien, I edited my issue to show what is my expected outcome.

Comment: Dear @Rolv Apneseth, I edited my issue to show what is my expected outcome.

Comment: `wl_names` == `keywords`?

Comment: @Corralien , yes. Another typo from my side.

Comment: So all you want to fix is `lower_dimensional_block` showing up on your output?

Comment: @Rolv Apneseth, Yes, I want to have it in front of the lines which have one of my `keywords`.

Comment: I would start with debugging your `if` statement to see if  `j in line` is getting triggered. You could also try just doing the `end=` part instead in another print statement.

Comment: The format might also be part of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you expect?

```
import fileinput
import re

keywords=['W_1', 'W_2']
KWDS = re.compile(fr'''\d+ \d+ "({'|'.join(keywords)})"'''
files = [f'mod{idx}.msh' for idx in range(2)]

with fileinput.input(files, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        print(f'{line.rstrip()} lower_dimensional_block'
                  if KWDS.match(line) else line.rstrip())
```

```
>>> %cat mod0.msh
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$PhysicalNames
13
1 10 "W_1" lower_dimensional_block
1 11 "W_2" lower_dimensional_block
2 8 "fault2"

>>> %cat mod0.msh.bak
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$PhysicalNames
13
1 10 "W_1"
1 11 "W_2"
2 8 "fault2"

>>> KWDS
re.compile(r'\d+ \d+ "(W_1|W_2)"', re.UNICODE)
```